# Mongoid 5 logs not going to production.log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

In my Rails application (Rails 4.2.4) I'm using mongoid 5.

When running in production, mongoid logs are not going to production.log. It's going to my thin logs instead.

I didn't have this issue with mongoid 3. Any thoughts on how could I keep all mongoid logs on production.log file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you use heroku? It is that the case, you need to add the rails_12factor gem as is explained here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#heroku-gems

At the end of Gemfile add:

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

Then run:

```
$ bundle install
```

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.